# block virtual keyboard from opening when all text selected in edittext field in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I wants to block virtual keyboard from opening when all text selected in edit text using select all option in context menu.please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);        
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(SearchForm.sf.searchQuery.getWindowToken(), 0);
```